# Simple query running longer than most other queries

Tags: mysqli

I know this isn't that big a deal since it's still fast (thanks to the power of mysqli!) but it's still really bugging me so i'd appreciate some thought on the matter.

Most of the queries on my dev site (windows localhost with appache and SQL) are taking 0.002 or less to run, even massive queries with 5 where's and 5 joins.

A simple insert on a table with two unique columns however is taking around 0.05 every single time. Again I know this isn't much, but in comparison to the other queries I really don't know why it's taking so long.

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `content_users` (
  `content_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `content_id_2`
  (`content_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `content_id` (`content_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the query i'm trying to run:

```
INSERT INTO `content_users` (`content_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (96, 4)
```

Can someone explain why this would be taking longer than any other query on my site to run?

At present the table only has 90 rows as it's a production environment, the live version should get into the ten's of thousands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have an Unique, I think you don't need to have the other two indexes.
MySQL uses only one index by query...

So, you can always use the Unique Key. There is no need for the other two...

The problem is, when you are inserting some data, you are updating the table, the unique index and the other 2 indexes.

Comment: Removing the two speeds things up slightly but not by much, I assumed they may be needed for doing a where on a single column, but removing them doesn't seem to effect the select's either so I suppose it's better without.

Answer (score 0):

What about indexes?  Your table uses composite key, and it costs a time to check for uniqueness.  And this will cost more when there are more users.  Create suitable indexes on columns used for key and performance will improve

Comment: As in the example there are 3 indexes, one for making sure the two columns are unique and one on each individual column. What other indexes could I put on other than these 3?